# Парализована работа сайта по причине превышения лимита обращения к API Я Картам

Tags: api

Проект simpla.pro просим оперативно помочь нам, готовы подключить платный пакет, что нужно сделать для восстановления работы сервиса?

Comment: Написать в Яндекс, очевидно.

Comment: Написали, ответа нет

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что данный ресурс не решает вопросов поддержки яндекс API.

Comment: Обратитесь в гугл-карты. :-)